# Xml on Android-Random Errors

Tags: android, xml

I am new to xml and android programming.Here is my xml code... I don't understand why i get random errors... I tried a lot of things(like changing "/>" with the normal way to end). I also tried an online xml checker but i got the same error so i hope you help me. I get a lot of errors, I know that I should tell you which are but they are so random. Maybe it's Eclipse's bug... Idk, thanks for reading this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Your total is 0"
android:textSize="45dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@id/tvDisplay"
/>

<Button
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Add one"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:id="@id/bAdd"
/>

<Button 
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Subtract one"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSide="20dp"
android:id="@id/bSub"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id declarations are incorrect: `android:id="@id/bSub"`.
It should be like `android:id="@+id/bSub"`. Note the "+" sign.

Comment: See this for more info on what Arhimed is talking about : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#idvalue

Answer (score 0):

also change line `android:textSide="20dp"` to `android:textSize="20dp"`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Your total is 0"
android:textSize="45dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
/>

<Button
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Add one"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:id="@+id/bAdd"
/>

<Button
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Subtract one"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:id="@+id/bSub"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```